# Implementing Merge Sort

Tags: c++, mergesort

So, I am trying to implement merge sort, which I conceptually understand but am obviously having great difficulty programming (I'm quite inexperienced). I have looked up previous posts which has helped, but I can't get past this point. I am currently having the following errors :

> 13:20: error: âSizeâ was not declared in this scope
>       mergesort(array[Size], low, mid);
>
> 41:20: error: invalid conversion from âintâ to âint*â [-fpermissive] 
>   mergesort(data[size], 0, size-1);
>
> 6:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of âvoid mergesort(int*, int,
>   int)â [-fpermissive]  void mergesort(int array[], int low, int high)

I am also very confused on how to proceed in general. I really don't know how to merge everything back together either. This did not seem like it would be nearly this difficult, but recursion really confuses me :/ Thanks for your help in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void merge(int[], int, int, int);

void mergesort(int array[], int low, int high)
{
    int mid;

    if(low < high)
    {
       mid = low + (high-low)/2;
       mergesort(array[Size], low, mid);
       mergesort(array[Size], mid+1, high);
       merge(array[Size], low, mid, high);
    }
}

void merge(int array, int low, int mid, int high)
{

}

int main()
{
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    int data[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> data[i];
    }

    mergesort(data[size], 0, size-1);
}
```

Comment: `void merge(int[], int, int, int);` != `void merge(int array, int low, int mid, int high)` (also, I would recommend that you put parameter names in your declaration). Also, `int data[size];` is not standard C++ when `size` is not a constant expression (from C99 and available as a compiler extension some compilers).

Comment: And your use of `array[Size]` makes no sense (`Size` is not declared) and that is not how you pass arrays.

Comment: mergesort(array[Size], low, mid); did you mean mergesort(array, low, mid);?

Comment: store data in `vector<int>`, pass them as `vector<int>&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data[Size]` attempts to get the `Size`th value from the array `data`. `Size` doesn't exist, and I don't think this is what you want. If you want to refer to the array itself, just use it's name: `data`.

You have the same problem later on with `data[size]`, except `size` does exist in this case. The error message is telling you that it can't convert an `int` to an `int*`. When you declare a function parameter like `int array[]`, it is actually just syntactic sugar for `int* array`. You are passing `data[size]` to this parameter, which attempts to access an `int` from `data` (although `size` is outside the bounds). Hence, the compiler does not know how to convert an `int` to a `int*` - they're different types.

Note that the following code is not standard C++, because variable-length arrays are not supported:

```
int size;
cin >> size;
int data[size];
```

That is, the size of an array needs to be known at compile-time, which `size` is not. You could instead use `std::vector<int> data(size);`.

Also, your declaration and definition for `merge` don't match - one takes an `int` as its first parameter, while the other takes `int[]`.

Comment: Quick side question: Is there an easy way to cin >> the numbers without having to push return & use space instead (with a loop)?

Comment: @Heather [Here's two ways to do it with a `std::vector`](http://ideone.com/871IKW).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are having difficulties understanding static arrays vs dynamic arrays.

I would suggest using std::vector instead of your data[size] declaration .

Regarding your errors :

Note that inside your mergesort function you are referring to Size which isn't defined . If you want to go with static array, I would suggest the following :

```
 #define SIZE 200
 ...
 int data[SIZE];
```

This will allow you to use the same SIZE thorughout the code.

However your array won't be the size of your input .

If you want to allocate an array at runtime , you need to change your code from

```
 int size;
 cin >> size;
 int data[size];
```

To

```
 int size;
 cin >> size;
 int* data = new int[size];
```

Then , in your mergesort function, you will have to pass the size as parameter.